# Link google docs with spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I really need your help. 
How can I link individual cells in a table with data in a document? 
In the table, I have calculations and I need to transfer the result to google docs with automatic update. As an example, "special insert - link" in Excel. 
Can I do this in google docs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still learning more about Google Docs so there maybe better ways of doing this. But here's a function to help you to identify the child index, the row index and the cell index of every table in a Google doc.  The second function can be a starting point for taking data out of the spreadsheet and putting it into that child index, row index, cell index.

```
function findMyTables() 
{
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  if(body)
  {
    var numChildren=body.getNumChildren();
    for(var i=0;i<numChildren;i++)
    {
      var child=body.getChild(i);
      if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE)
      {
        s+=br + 'ChildIndex = ' + i;
        s+=br + 'Cell[row index][column index] ';
        var numrows = child.asTable().getNumRows();
        for(var j=0;j<numrows;j++)
        {
          var numcells=child.asTable().getRow(j).getNumCells();
          for(var k=0;k<numcells;k++)
          {
            var celltxt=child.asTable().getCell(j, k).editAsText().getText();
            s+=br + '<strong>Cell[' + j + '][' + k + ']= </strong>' + '<span style="color:#ff0000;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">' + celltxt + '</span>';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(600).setHeight(450);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'My Tables');
```

Getting the data out of the spreadsheet is relatively straight forward but I find that getting into the Google Doc is a little more difficult.  Here's a function that takes the child index, row index and the cell index and enters your data into the Google Docs.  At the present time I have not resolved why it changes the formatting. I'm hoping that one of the big guns on this site will take pity upon us poor empty minded souls and enlighten us.

```
function saveChildTableCellChanges(childidx,rowidx,cellidx,text)
{
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var child=doc.getBody().getChild(childidx);
  child.asTable().getRow(rowidx).getCell(cellidx).editAsText().setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live **without auto-update** (*tried some suggestions from here and google support forum, none worked for me*) you can just copy multiple cells (*won't work for single cell*) form Google's spreadsheet (**ctrl+C**) and paste it in your Document (**ctrl+V**) you will then be asked to choose:

> Paste table:
>
> [x] Link to spreadsheet <- you want this option
>
> [ ] Pased unlinked

**The above will not show if you paste a single cell!**

> Workarounds to show as *"fake single cell"*:
>
> 1. Copy & paste two cells one has your data and the other is empty, in spreadsheet hide the column or row with empty cell, update the table in Doc.
> 2. Copy & paste two cells one has your data and the other is empty, next modify empty cell border to be 0 pt wide and drag it to be as small as possible (*not to disrupt flow of your Document*).

If because of your's sheet layout it's hard to find empty cells next to your data cells just create another sheet (*it can than be set as "protected" if you like*) in that spreadsheet referencing only the data you would like to link in your Doc and copy form this new sheet.

---

REMEMBER!
You will have to update manually, your Doc should show you and update button above linked table every time the content is out of sync.